# PHP-HTML5-Form - My query-generated dropdown posts a blank value

Tags: php, mysql, html, post

When I load my page, the value of the variable, $v_UpdateONE, is "Select Version". When I select a version, the value goes blank. 
I need to grab the selected value for use in a DB update statement.
Thank you for any assistance.   -James

```
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="Update.php" WIDTH="50">
<?php

$avQuery = "SELECT $v_software1 FROM version_master.vermas_availableversions WHERE $v_software1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY SortCol DESC";
  $a_AvailVers = mysql_query($avQuery);
  #_Version dropdown box
  echo "<select NAME='AvailVersONE' ONCHANGE=submit()>";
  echo "<option>Select Version</option>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($a_AvailVers)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['$v_software1'] . "'>" . $row[$v_software1] . "</option>";
  }
 echo "</select>";

 $v_UpdateONE = $_POST['AvailVersONE'];
 echo $v_UpdateONE;

?>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in

```
value='" . $row['$v_software1'] . "'
```

Since `$v_software1` is in single quotes, it will be literal `$v_software1`.

Try removing the quotes -

```
value='" . $row[$v_software1] . "'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post before you can read $_POST data.

Form File

```
 <FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="Update.php" WIDTH="50">
<?php

$avQuery = "SELECT $v_software1 FROM version_master.vermas_availableversions WHERE $v_software1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY SortCol DESC";
  $a_AvailVers = mysql_query($avQuery);
  #_Version dropdown box
  echo "<select NAME='AvailVersONE' id='AvailVersONE' ONCHANGE=submit()>";
  echo "<option>Select Version</option>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($a_AvailVers)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['$v_software1'] . "'>" . $row[$v_software1] . "</option>";
  }
 echo "</select>"; 
?>
<button type="submit"> <!-- this will draw a submit button -->
</FORM>
```

then on your Update.php

```
<?php

$v_UpdateONE = $_POST['AvailVersONE'];
echo $v_UpdateONE;

?>
```

Sometimes, the ID needs to be filled up (browser dependent)

Comment: Thank you. The response from Sean, above, worked great. But since you took the time to help I wanted to test your maneuver as well for feedback. With Sean's solution, your solution also worked and provided the added benefit of placing my post elsewhere if needed.